# Node Spawn API not parsing string args correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use the spawn api to do a mongo import. Unfortunately, the string parsing the command seems to be breaking. Right now it thinks `--db` is really `db`. If I add two more `--` something else breaks. If I fix that something else breaks. How can I use the spwan API to accomplish doing a full mongo import?

Common errors have been checked for (filename, variable names etc.)

Code:

```
   const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

   let argumentString = `--db <DB> --collection ${m} --file '/home/${obj.filename}' --jsonArray`
            console.log(argumentString)
            child = spawn('mongoimport', [argumentString]);

        child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('stdout: ' + data);
            resolve()
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('stderr: ' + data);
            reject()
        });
```

LOG: 
`--db <DB> --collection users --file /home/users-backup-2018-08-20.json --jsonArray`

Error:  error parsing command line options: unknown option "db  --collection users --file /home/users-backup-2018-08-20.json --jsonArray"

Comment: Have you tried using alias flags like `-d <DB> -c ${m} --file '~/home/${obj.filename}' --jsonArray` putting the full file path for the file?